# Android: do BroadcastReceivers stop if an app is killed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

If a declare a BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml, the reciever works, as it should, even on device boot when my application hasn't started yet, but if I force my app to stop from Settings the receiver seems to break down too.
Can it be that "Force stop" in Android 2.2 also makes some cleanup after the application (including BroadcastReceivers or maybe alarms set by the app in AlarmManager which should broadcast the intents I receive)?
By the way, how can I see in Eclipse all broadcasts being sent in the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psycho,

Force Stop should not be used to attempt to test your app from a "non-running" state.  I would say the behavior is "undefined" at best.  It is not uncommon that after using Force Stop on an app, that you must manually restart it to get ANY of its usability back (including `BroadcastReceiver`).  If your app is able to receive `BroadcastReceiver`events including the BOOT_COMPLETE `Broadcast` than you shouldn't really need to test it further.

I believe the intended purpose of Force Stop was to completely stop an annoying app's functionality.  If an app is running in the background often because its receiving a lot of broadcasts and restarting, wouldn't you think Force Stop should prevent that behavior until the app is manually restarted by the user?

Also, I don't believe there is a way to view `Broadcast` events from Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remember that Force Stop is a special case. I tried another way of closing my application - dividing by zero :) - and everything's OK, both alarms and a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse there is no way to see the "broadcast is sent" 

Also If you have registered the Broadcast in manifest for which you want to receive the event then system will call onReceived method